# How to get user permissions of user currently in Django admin site

Tags: django

I have certain fields that I would only like displayed to certain admins when they are in the admin site.  I am looking into using `list_display` to do this but first need to figure out a way of determining which user is currently viewing the admin site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you pass the request object everywhere, the solution is generally to use thread local storage and some middleware that updates the value on each request.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2179/